# Website hosted in Firebase won't load with "www."

Tags: firebase-hosting

I am pretty new in the web world. I created website, hosted it in Firebase Hosting but I found out that if using "www." Before the full url, then it leads "couldn't load that page". Why is it like this?

test.firebaseapp.com - This is working

www.test.firebaseapp.com - This is not workin

The config that I can do on my end is the Deployment Configuration which is .json file, which in my case looks like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "Pedia",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Opening the website in the chrome with "www." I get this:
[image]

Should I redirect it?

Comment: I'm no firebase specialist, but surely there must be some kind of configuration you could show us?

Comment: @Ahatius you are absolutely right. I edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To redirect www.test.firebaseapp.com to test.firebaseapp.com then you need to add CNAME record.

To redirect test.firebaseapp.com to www.test.firebaseapp.com, you need to add A record.

Kindly check your DNS entries for the domain.

Answer (score 4):

Firebase no longer supports `CNAME` entries for **www** and suggests only to use `A Record` with both **@** and **www**.

Also, you'll have to provide redirection at firebase console too, refer screenshot below [image]